# 3d points projected to y-z plane and colorized according x-velocity

Tags: plotting, color

I have a set of 3d positions and velocities of paticles:

```
SeedRandom[1];
posdata = RandomReal[10, {1000, 3}];
veldata = RandomReal[{-0.5, +0.5}, {1000, 3}];
```

As first I can project all positions to the z-y plane and colorize them according their x position:

```
clfun[val_] := Blend[{ Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, val];

{xmin, xmax} = {0, 10};

legend = BarLegend[{clfun[#/xmax] &, {xmin, xmax}}, 
   LegendLabel -> "x", LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 300}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 15}];

zyplot = Show[
   Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], clfun[(#[[1]]/10)], 
       Point[{#[[3]], #[[2]]}]} & /@ posdata, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"z", ""}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20}, 
    ImageSize -> 400]];

Legended[Graphics[
  Inset[zyplot, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]], 
  AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@zyplot], legend]
```

The result is:

[image]

**How can I colorize the projected positions according to the x-velocity?**
I would like also to show at right the corresponding legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xvelzypos = posdata;
xvelzypos[[All, 1]] = veldata[[All, 1]];
{xmin2, xmax2} = MinMax@veldata[[All, 1]];
legend2 = BarLegend[{clfun[Rescale[#, {xmin2, xmax2}]] &, { xmin2, xmax2}}, 
  LegendLabel -> "x", LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 300}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 15}]
xvzyplot = Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], 
       clfun[Rescale[#[[1]], {xmin2, xmax2}]], 
       Point[{#[[3]], #[[2]]}]} & /@ xvelzypos, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"z", ""}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20}, 
    ImageSize -> 400]];

Legended[Graphics[Inset[xvzyplot, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]], 
  AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@zyplot], legend2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is very smart solution ;-) to replace x by vx. In principle I could produce also a list which contains all positions and all velocities and then select the appropriate indices, or?

Comment: May I ask you something in addition: Is there a built in function which could produce something like a smoothed density plot of such a projection?

Comment: Lenoil, `ListDensityPlot` maybe?